# Parse Server - How to call a Job defined in the Cloud code from app.js or index.js

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I am with Parse Server 3.0. I would like to call a Job from app.js or index.js (depending on how the Express JS app was generated).

In my cloud code `main.js`

```
// JOB
Parse.Cloud.job("myJob", async (request) =>  {
    // params: passed in the job call
    // headers: from the request that triggered the job
    // log: the ParseServer logger passed in the request
    // message: a function to update the status message of the job object
    const { params, headers, log, message } = request;
    message("I just started");
    const query_log = new Parse.Query("Log");
    const unique_aas_names = await query_log.distinct("aas_name");
    // E.g.: {"result":["MHA-L29","MHA-L30"]}
    message("I just finished");
    console.log("unique_aas_names.length: " + unique_aas_names.length);
    return unique_aas_names;
});
```

Is it possible to call the Job from the index.js in a Parse Server app?

Comment: I think it is not possible to directly call Parse Cloud Job within the app other than calling the rest API. Another approach is to write the implementation of the job function separately and then use node-scheduler or similar libraries instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the job using the Parse JS SDK with this command:

```js
Parse.Cloud.startJob('myJob', myJobParams);
```